# No me controla bien el argumento y no muestra correctamente el contenido del fichero

Tags: c, archivo

Buenas tengo que realizar un ejercicio en el que dado por la terminal una palabra como "hola" me muestre la cadena entera donde se vea ese hola. Pero antes de eso tengo que controlar que los argumentos introducidos a la hora de filtrar no sean números ni sintaxis raras. He probado la función isdigit pero no me salta la comprobación no entiendo el porque. Luego a la hora de mostrar las cadenas dentro del fichero me muestra solo una linea y ni si quiera es la primera y con caracteres especiales (esta en catalán).

```
 #define MAXCADENA 200
 #include <locale.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
       setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
       FILE *f;
       char cadenaMostrar[MAXCADENA];

       if(argc!=3) printf("error de parametres");
       else if(!isdigit(argv[2])) printf("Tiene que ser caracter o string no un numero");
       else{
            printf("\nNombre del fichero %s\n",argv[1]);
           f=fopen(argv[1],"r+");

           if(f==NULL) printf("No se ha podido abrir el fichero");
           else{
                   fgets(cadenaMostrar,MAXCADENA,f);

                   printf("\n%s",cadenaMostrar);

                   fclose(f);
               }
            }
            return 0;
  }
```

Os dejo unas capturas de lo que me pasa con la cadena, contar que aquí hago un EncontrarTabla.exe text.txt 3 y el 3 no hace la comprobación y entra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: isDigit no valida una cadena completa si no un solo carácter. si haces isDigit( argv[2]) estas pasandole una cadena amigo. Debes iterar la cadena carácter por carácter y a cada uno  preguntar si viene con un dígito. Por otro lado se oye raro esto. ¿no te parece más sencillo checar si cada carácter es una letra en lugar de chechar si es un dígito? Además no estas checando los caracteres raros.

Comment: Tiene sentido lo de probar carácter a carácter, te refieres en usar fgetc...? El tema de caracteres nos habían comentado que con añadir la biblioteca **#include <locale.h>** y un **setlocale(LC_ALL,"");** no deberíamos de tener problemas con los acentos y caracteres, pero no funciona.

Comment: No amigo, fgetc es para leer de un flujo de entrada. El argv[2] no es un flujo. De tu código entiendo que ahí viene el nombre del archivo y quieres ver si en el solo hay caracteres. Para eso hay que iterar los caracteres de argv[2], iterar es poner un ciclo aquí no hablo de funciones, debes iterar.

Comment: Perfecto, comprobare a ver si me funciona. Con el tema de caracteres especiales debo de crear una función y controlarlo ?

Comment: El compilador como mínimo debería de lanzarte alguna advertencia en esta linea `if(!isdigit(argv[2]))`, puesto `argv` es un puntero a puntero a `char` y al hacer `argv[2]` estarías pasando un `char*` (es decir, estás pasando una dirección de memoria), cuando el parámetro de la función espera un `int` (hay una incompatibilidad de tipos). *Recomiendo* mirar **siempre las advertencias del compilador.**

Comment: Con el tema de caracteres especiales debo de crear una función y controlarlo ? Puedes, esto ayudaría a ir separando en partes más pequeñas la lógica de tu programa. Recuerda también que el compilador fue hecho para ayudarte, como comenta MrDave1999 revisa las advertencias y errores que puedan surgir al compilar tu código.